# Nominal Attributes Incompitablity Weka : ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: machine-learning, weka, indexoutofboundsexception, naivebayes, arff

I have a arff file, which is used as a training set in my java code. All of the attributes in this are nominal. The problem is that when I retrieve my data from database which act as testing data ; the header that is generated for the nominal attribute is a bit different for the train and test set. And that causes a problem for the predictor. For example the headers could be as follows:

In training set
`@attribute study_hrs {0,1,2,3,4,5}`

In testing set
`@attribute study_hrs {3,2,1,0,4,5}`

As you can see it is logically same values but the sequence differ. But how could i resolve this issue. I have to take testing data from database dynamically, I cannot create a arff file.

Following is my code snippet:

```
public static Instances dBDataInstances(String dbQuery,String user,String pass) throws Exception{
        InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
        query.setUsername(user);
        query.setPassword(pass);
        query.setQuery(dbQuery);
        // You can declare that your data set is sparse
        // query.setSparseData(true);
        Instances data = query.retrieveInstances();
        return data;
    }

   .......
   .......

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("AnalyKT.arff");
    //training data
    Instances dataKT = new Instances(datafile);
    dataKT=convertNumericToNominal(dataKT);
    dataKT=convertStringToNominal(dataKT);
    dataKT.setClassIndex(dataKT.numAttributes() - 3);



    Classifier nB1 = new NaiveBayes();
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataKT);
    eval.crossValidateModel(nB1, dataKT, 10, new Random(1));
    System.out.println("Estimated Accuracy: "+Double.toString(eval.pctCorrect()));

            //Train a new classifier
    Classifier nB2 = new NaiveBayes();
    nB2.buildClassifier(dataKT);  //predict with this model

    String query="select Student.rollno as rollno, study_hrs, health, ..............";
    Instances testKtData=dBDataInstances(query, "root", "root");

    testKtData=convertNumericToNominal(testKtData);
    testKtData=convertStringToNominal(testKtData);

    testKtData.setClassIndex(testKtData.numAttributes() - 3);
      System.out.println(""+testKtData.numAttributes()+"-"+dataKT.numAttributes()+"-"+dataKT.equalHeadersMsg(testKtData));
    eval.evaluateModel(nB2, testKtData);

            System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
 }
}
```

It is giving me following output with error:

```
Estimated Accuracy: 83.33333333333333
28-28-Attributes differ at position 11:
Labels differ at position 1: 0 != 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
    at  weka.estimators.DiscreteEstimator.getProbability(DiscreteEstimator.java:111)
    at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.distributionForInstance(NaiveBayes.java:369)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluationForSingleInstance(Evaluation.java:1961)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Evaluation.java:1999)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1875)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:671)
    at Predictor.main(Predictor.java:137)
```

I am stuck! Thanks for any help.